# Responses to questions with modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs, questions, verb-forms, responses

I was wondering if someone could tell me which answer of the questions bellow sounds incorrect grammatically from among the following list:

> - Could I ask you something? → Yes, of course you could.
> - May I ask you something? → Yes, of course you may.
> - I wonder if I might ask you something? → Yes, of course you might.

For me only the answer to the first question grammatically appears to be incorrect. Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, I think, most speakers would translate the 'remote' modals (past forms signifying tentativity or indirectness) in #1 and #3 into ordinary indicatives:

- Yes, of course you can.
- Yes, of course you may.

But it's not at all a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: Do you mean that in reply to the third sentence I have to answer with 'may' as well?

Comment: @A-friend Yes. Your *might* expresses an unwillingness to demand; the answering *may* expresses a willingness to grant.

Comment: Strictly speaking "I wonder if I might ask you something?" is not a question at all.  And a confirmation to it is "of course you ***do*** (wonder)". :-)